# SonarQube Installation with Oracle DB - Getting user does not exists

Tags: java, oracle, sonarqube

Having trouble installing SonarQube 3.7 with Oracle - always getting *ORA-01435: User does not exist*.

Before pasting the stack trace here are the steps I followed to verify

1. Was able to connect to the same user using SQL Plus and SQL Developer.
2. Was able to create a table and insert some dummy data for the same user to make sure it is working fine.
3. Change in Oracle thin JDBC URL throws error saying that URL is malformed.

Here is my *sonar.properties* file

```
sonar.jdbc.username:                       test_sonar
sonar.jdbc.password:                       test_sonar
sonar.jdbc.dialect:                        oracle
sonar.jdbc.schema:                         test_sonar
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOST)(PORT=MYPORT))(failover=yes))(CONNECT_DATA=(service_name=MYSERVICE)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                select 1 from dual
sonar.hibernate.default_schema:            test_sonar
```

Using the above properties I was able to run SolarQube 2.8 successfully with out any errors but couldn't run any other version from 3.0.

Appreciate your help.

**Stacktrace**

```
2013.09.03 16:09:46 INFO  o.s.s.p.ServerImpl  SonarQube Server / 3.7 / 7c385c2c648967302cf69e08f56c0da135b3e5e9
2013.09.03 16:09:46 INFO  o.s.c.p.Database  Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=MYHOST)(PORT=MYPORT))(failover=yes))(CONNECT_DATA=(service_name=MYSERVICE)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
2013.09.03 16:09:47 ERROR o.s.c.p.Database  Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixe
d by 'sonar.jdbc.').
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01435: user does not exist
)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:141) [sonar-core-3.7.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:70) [sonar-core-3.7.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) [picocontainer-2.14.3
.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) [picocontainer-2.1
4.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) [picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:87) [sonar-plugin-api-3.7.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startDatabaseConnectors(Platform.java:193) [classes/:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:134) [classes/:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33) [classes/:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:746) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.
v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:238) [jetty-servlet-7.6.11.v20130520.jar
:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520
]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:689) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v2013
0520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:482) [jetty-webapp-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v201
30520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229) [jetty-server-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11
.v20130520]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64) [jetty-util-7.6.11.v20130520.jar:7.6.11.v201
30520]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this issue, and managed to solve it but setting the schema name to uppercase, like this:

```
sonar.jdbc.schema:                         TEST_SONAR
```

Also, there's no need to have both `sonar.jdbc.schema` and `sonar.hibernate.default_schema`, as the second property actually overrides the first one.

Comment: Thank You it worked fine after the change. ( completely forgot to update )